# scrollLeft setter is not working (Angular, jqLitle)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, jqlite

I have this code

```
var input = element.find('input').eq(0);

scope.focus = function() {
  if (!input.length) return;
  input[0].focus();
  input[0].select();
  var divWrapper = input.parent('.tags')[0];
  divWrapper.scrollLeft = divWrapper.scrollWidth;
  console.log(divWrapper.scrollWidth);
  console.log(divWrapper.scrollLeft);
};
```

This is inside a directive fnLink and focus is called when ui is changed this because use overflow: hidden and input disapear when many items on left... so I need to scroll to far right and keep input visible.
The

```
divWrapper.scrollLeft = divWrapper.scrollWidth;
```

works fine on chrome dev tools but when focus is called don't update the scrollLeft attribute.

Comment: how you called `scope.focus` method & does it belongs to controller?

Comment: I am calling on a service... where has the scope with focus method... I get the right dom elements but doesn't update the value.

Comment: you can always use `divWrapper.style.left = -divWrapper.scrollWidth`

Comment: Thanks, I tested but is not working. Looks like setters are not working.